# Select Option and disable same option in other dropdowns

Tags: angular, typescript, select

In my Anuglar App I generate some select boxes the amount can vary. Every selectbox has the same options. What I want to do is if I select a option in one selectbox the same option should be disabled in all other selectboxes so no other selectbox can have the same value at the same time. If I choos a other option in that selectbox the previous one should be enable in all other selectboxes and the new one should be disabled.

I could bring it to that point that it works with two selectboxes. When there are more it doesn't work like it should.

This is the function which is called by onChange of a selectbox:

```
public disableAlreadyUsedOption(group: any, dropDownId: any): void {
if (group.usecase === 'usage_ds' || group.usecase === 'usage_dg') {
  this.listOfdropDowns[group.usecase].forEach((element, indexOfForeach) => {
    const tmpDropDownId = group.usecase  + '_' + indexOfForeach;
    if (dropDownId !== tmpDropDownId) {
      const op = document.getElementById(tmpDropDownId).getElementsByTagName('option');
      for (let i = 1; i < op.length; i++) {
        if (op[i].value === group.optionValue) {
          op[i].disabled = true;
          op[i].className = 'disabledOtions';
        } else {
          op[i].disabled = false;
          op[i].className = '';
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a forbidden values array to disable the checkboxes and their options. The indexes would represent which group has been checked, and the value which option has been checked.

```
forbiddenValues = [];

optionsGroups = [
  ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'],
  ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'],
  ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'],
];

onGroupOptionChecked(optionGroup, optionValue) {
  const indexOfGroup = this.optionsGroups.indexOf(optionGroup);
  const indexOfOption = this.forbiddenValues[indexOfGroup].indexOf(optionValue);
  this.forbiddenValues[indexOfGroup] = indexOfOption;
}
```

Now, you can iterate over your options, and deactivate them very simply :

```html
<option-group *ngFor="let group of optionsGroups; let groupIndex = index">
   <option-value *ngFor="let option of group; let optionIndex = index" 
     [value]="option"
     [disabled]="forbiddenValues.indexOf(optionIndex) !== -1">{{ option }}</option-value>
</option-group>
```

Comment: Was my mistake sorry, there are no checkboxes only select boxes (dropdown)

Comment: @WeSt the principle remains though ! all you have to do is change the HTML tags